# an error occurred while deploying the file. install failed conflicting provider

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, genymotion

I generate apk file for my project but when I drag and drop it to genymotion I see this error:

```
an error occurred while deploying the file. install failed conflicting provider
```

Comment: I find my problem. It was for the same installed project in my pc with different password for keystore.

Comment: Thanks you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

I had same problem, solved it by uncheck `Verify apps over USB` under `Developer settings`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Actually @WenChao's answer is the solution, but for me this option was disabled. in this case you need to run following command (*in order to uncheck `Verify apps over USB` option*):

```
adb shell settings put global verifier_verify_adb_installs 0
```

Make sure `adb` is connected to emulator (*run `adb devices` to see connected devices*)

If you want to check the option (*are you crazy?*) just pass `1` instead of `0` in above command.

Comment: It didn't work for me

Answer (score -1):

it's too late ...

But this Ans does provide some  help for others :)

```
Eror : an error occurred while deploying the file.
```

1. Open Genymotion
2. Go to Setting
3. In settings window select ADB
4. Under ADB tool connections setting **select**
   **Use Genymotion Android tools(default)**  radio button.
5. Now **Start Your Virtual Device**

now drag and drop work perfectly :)

Comment: No, It didn't work